# Angle between two $n$ dimensional vectors

Tags: trigonometry, vector-spaces

Let $u$ and $v$ be two $n$-dimensional vectors and ending at coordinates $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ and $(b_1,\dots,b_n)$ respectively. Is there a way to calculate the angle between these two vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may rearrange the dot product formula $\mathbf a \cdot \mathbf b = \lVert \mathbf a \rVert \lVert \mathbf b \rVert \cos\theta$ for the angle $\theta$ between the vectors $\mathbf a = (a_1,\dots,a_n)$ and $\mathbf b = (b_1,\dots,b_n)$.